# how specify select function foreach option in UI selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, select-menu

I'm using [UI Selectmenu](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) in my project

UI selectmenu has a select option to set select behavior for all selectmenu options like :

```
$('.anything').
    selectmenu({
        select : function(event, options) { 
            spec_function('2')
        } 
    });
```

How can I set a specific select behavior for **each** option or a **specific** option **not all** ?

Comment: @ClydeFrog Can you explain more please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use switch-case statement and as SurjithSM says, send the ID of what option you're selecting. As such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.anything').
    selectmenu({
        select : function(event, options){ 
            switch(options['value']) { 
                case 'some_value_1': 
                    // anycode 1 ...
                    break;
                case 'some_value_2': 
                    // anycode 2 ...
                    break;
                case 'some_value_3': 
                    // anycode 3 ...
                    break;
                default:
                    // default anycode  ...
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. but it may need some modifications : 
`$('.anything').selectmenu({
                                                        select : function(event, options){
                                                            switch(options['value'])` .. so on **please modify your code to select your the best answer**

Comment: sorry, it may be a miss understand here , I just typed the modification part of your code as in comments it's hard to write a full code. so the full code will be : ` $('.anything').selectmenu({ select : function(event, options){ switch(options['value']) { case 'p.hotel_cat': // anycode
                     break; }  }}); `